# Get date using subprocess python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I used subprocess to get information on a directory in my VM.

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.getoutput("ssh -i /path-to-key ubuntu@IP ls -l /opt/orientdb/databases")
print(output)
```

and i get the output as

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 25  2019 friendship_graph_434
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 18  2019 friendship_graph_453
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  3  2019 friendship_graph_465
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct  2  2019 friendship_graph_468
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct  4  2019 friendship_graph_471
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 15  2019 friendship_graph_477
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov  6  2019 friendship_graph_471
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 29  2020 friendship_graph_496
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 27  2019 friendship_graph_497
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec  3  2019 friendship_graph_49
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec  4  2019 friendship_graph_498
```

How can i get just the date from the above output? Thank you

Comment: Not sure that using python around your `ssh` command does anything for you. If you want the content of the files, think you should consider copying them with `scp` command maybe.

Comment: What do you mean by "just the data"?

Comment: you can always parse the output, but probably you better use python code to get the dates. e.g. look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293599/paramiko-get-files-by-modified-time/55933432

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry i had a typo, i meant date.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire ssh helps in actually logging into the VM.

Comment: You want to use `--time-style=long-iso` to get consistent results independent of language

Comment: @Somethingwhatever Yes I am aware that `ssh` logs into the machine. The `scp` command is related to `ssh` and copies files to and from a remote machine using the same technology.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Using a tool like `stat` instead makes the output a lot easier to handle, and probably simplifies your code to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, since you are already using a subprocess might as well use it all the way:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.getoutput("ssh -i /path-to-key ubuntu@IP ls -l /opt/orientdb/databases | awk -F' ' '{print $6, $7, $8}'")
print(output)
```

should get you output in the format:

Apr 25  2019

Jul 18  2019

etc.

So to explain what I did. I added the following to your command: `"| awk -F' ' 'print{$6, $7, $8}'"`

The first token: `|` is a pipe, which is basically saying use the output of the last command, in this case `ls` as the input for the next command, in this case `awk`

`awk` is awesome. In this case, what I'm doing is specifying a delimiter with `-F ' '`, saying to split the lines provided based on space. awk seems to handle the scenarios where there are multiple spaces well enough (Say between April_25 and Feb__2 for example)

then `'print{$6, $7, $8}'` is saying that based on that delimiter, print out the 6th, 7th, and 8th columns, which should correspond to your month / day / year

From there it's very simple date processing in python as mentioned in other answers. We'll use the datetime library's strptime function, which takes a string, and some format, and returns a datetime object you can manipulate and use. The format is pretty straightforward to use after you check out the [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
lines = data.splitlines()
format = '%b %d  %Y'# Will parse strings like April 25 2019
# format = '%Y-%m-%d' will parse strings like 2019-04-25

for line in lines:
    date = datetime.strptime(line, format)
    print(date)
    # should get something like datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 25, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a great way of doing it. However what if i am using long-iso and getting the date in this format, `2021-04-08` . What format should i use?

Comment: As always, documentation is your best friend :P https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes lists the various formats for the datetime library, so in the case you mentioned you'd use "%Y-%m-%d" as your format string.

Comment: Thanks!! Accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to search for the dates.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import re

pattern = re.compile(
    r"\b((?:(?:Jan)|(?:Feb)|(?:Mar)|(?:Apr)|(?:May)|(?:Jun)|(?:Jul)|(?:Aug)|(?:Sep)|(?:Oct)|(?:Nov)|(?:Dec))\s+\d\d?\s+(?:[12]\d\d\d))\b"
)

format = '%b %d  %Y'

data = '''\
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 25  2019 friendship_graph_434
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 18  2019 friendship_graph_453
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  3  2019 friendship_graph_465
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct  2  2019 friendship_graph_468
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct  4  2019 friendship_graph_471
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 15  2019 friendship_graph_477
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov  6  2019 friendship_graph_471
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 29  2020 friendship_graph_496
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 27  2019 friendship_graph_497
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec  3  2019 friendship_graph_49
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec  4  2019 friendship_graph_498
'''

lines = data.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    m = pattern.search(line)
    s = m.group(1)
    d = datetime.strptime(s, format)
    print(d.date())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have some code like this:

```
import calendar

output_split = output.split("\n")
dates = []
months = {month: index for index, month in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if month}
for i in output_split:
    y = i[29:-21].split()
    dates.append(f"{y[1]}/{months[y[0]]}/{y[2]}")
print(dates)
```

Comment: I am getting 
`months = {month: index for index, month in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if month}
NameError: name 'calendar' is not defined`

Comment: @Somethingwhatever: `import calendar`: [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html)

Comment: `dates.append(f"{y[1]}/{months[y[0]]}/{y[2]}")
IndexError: list index out of range`